# How to delete line containing a string when this line contins only two values?

Tags: sed

I want to delete all the lines of file have a specific string if these lines contains only two values (columns). I tried with this sed but this delete all lines containing the string

```
sed '/string/d' file
```

ex
for XX string the input file is

```
A B C D 
XX 5 6 
XX 2
XX 1 2 3
```

the output file is

```
A B C D 
XX 5 6 
XX 1 2 3
```

Comment: Could be a 3rd column without value, and a 4th with value?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity ,  the string is always in the 1st column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using the pattern section to evaluate to true
to default print the line:

```
awk -v str="XX" '
  NR == 1 || $1 != str || NF != 2
' file
```

Assuming the target string is matched in first field only.